# PHP Querypath selector for HTML5 data attribute

Tags: php, querypath

Is it possible to use PHP querypath to get the HTML5 data attribute of a DOM element?
E.g:

```
//HTML element
<div data-foo-attribute="whatever"></div>

//PHP
$attribute = $mydiv->attr('data-foo-attribute'); //does not work
```

Comment: YES, You can. http://querypath.org/

Comment: Yes, as in a) "you can use attr('data-foo-attribute') for that" or b) "yes, there is a documentation which you can check yourself"? In case of option b) , I don't see how this (http://querypath.org/classes/QueryPath.DOMQuery.html#method_attr) answers my question =)
Anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can use `attr('data-foo-attribute')` for that

```php
$html = '<div data-foo-attribute="whatever"></div>';
$qp = htmlqp($html);
$mydiv = $qp->find('div');

$attribute = $mydiv->attr('data-foo-attribute');
```

Or you can use `data()`:

```php
$html = '<div data-foo-attribute="whatever"></div>';
$qp = htmlqp($html);
$mydiv = $qp->find('div');

$attribute = $mydiv->data('foo-attribute');
```

Comment: It works indeed. I did not work out before, since $mydiv was pointing to the wrong DOM element in the first place and I did not realize it. Thanks.